# A simple question about determinant

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $a_i=[a_{i1},a_{i2},\ldots,a_{in}]\in \mathbb{R}^n$, for $i=1,\ldots,n-1$.
How to prove that

$$
\sum_{i_1,\ldots,i_{n-1}=1}^n   \varepsilon_{i,i_1,\ldots,i_{n-1}}  a_{1,i_1} a_{2,i_2}\cdots a_{n-1, i_{n-1}}=
(-1)^{1+i} \det \left [ \begin{array}{rrrrr}
a_{11} & \ldots &\hat{a_{1i}} & \ldots & a_{1n}\\
a_{21} & \ldots & \hat{a_{i2}} & \ldots & a_{2n} \\
 \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots \\
 a_{n-1,1}& \ldots & \hat{a_{n-1,i}} & \ldots & a_{n-1,n}
\end{array} \right  ],
$$

for $i=1,\ldots,n$,
where $ \varepsilon_{i,i_1,\ldots,i_{n-1}}=1$ or $-1$ or $0$ depending on whether  $(i,i_1,\ldots,i_{n-1})$ is an even permutation  or an odd permutation or it is not a  permutation of numbers $1,\ldots,n$.

(Symbol $\hat{a_{ij}}$ means that $a_{ij}$ is omitted.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RHS is the determinant of $\pmatrix{0&\ldots&0&1&0&\ldots& 0 \\\
a_{11}&\ldots& a_{1,i-1}&a_{1,i}&a_{1,i+1}&\ldots &a_{1,n}\\\ 
a_{21}&\ldots &a_{2,i-1}&a_{2,i}&a_{2,i+1}&\ldots &a_{2,n}\\\
\vdots&\ldots&\vdots& \vdots&\vdots&\cdots &\vdots\\\
a_{n-1,1}&\ldots& a_{n-1,i-1}&a_{n-1,i}&a_{n-1,i+1}&\ldots &a_{n-1,n}
 }$, and putting $b_{ij}=a_{ij}$ if $i\leq n-1$, $a_{nj}=\delta_{ij}$ it's equal to $\sum_{\sigma\in\Sigma_n}\varepsilon(\sigma)\prod_{j=1}^nb_{j,\sigma(j)}$. In fact you have to consider the permutations which fix $i$, which will give you the result.

Comment: Maybe the "zero-one" row should be in the first row? Thanks a lot for answer.

Comment: You are right, it should indeed the first. Thanks for pointing this out.